# jdbc drivers -naming convention not understantable

Tags: jdbc

as i am going through the link, i got a good knowledge of the stuff
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver#Type_3_Driver_-_Network-Protocol_Driver

but not able to understand the bold words :
Type 2 Driver - **Native-API** Driver Or also called Partial Java Driver
Type 3 Driver - **Network-Protocol** Driver
Type 4 Driver - **Native-Protocol** Driver

please help me to understand these bold words, what they specify wrt to the driver

Answer (score 4):

This is well explained in the [JDBC tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/gettingstarted.html#step3):

> There are many possible implementations of JDBC drivers. These
> implementations are categorized as follows:
>
> - Type 1: Drivers that implement the JDBC API as a mapping to another data access API, such as ODBC (Open Database Connectivity).
>   Drivers of this type are generally dependent on a native library,
>   which limits their portability. The JDBC-ODBC Bridge is an example of
>   a Type 1 driver.
>
> Note: The JDBC-ODBC Bridge should be considered a transitional solution. It is not supported by Oracle. Consider using this only if
> your DBMS does not offer a Java-only JDBC driver.
>
> - Type 2: Drivers that are written partly in the Java programming language and partly in native code. These drivers use a native client
>   library specific to the data source to which they connect. Again,
>   because of the native code, their portability is limited. Oracle's OCI
>   (Oracle Call Interface) client-side driver is an example of a Type 2
>   driver.
> - Type 3: Drivers that use a pure Java client and communicate with a middleware server using a database-independent protocol. The
>   middleware server then communicates the client's requests to the data
>   source.
> - Type 4: Drivers that are pure Java and implement the network protocol for a specific data source. The client connects directly to
>   the data source.